# How to store textbox input into a two dimensional array?

Tags: vb.net

okay so i have two textboxes for user input, and i need help storing these into a single two dimensional array.
for 49 columns and two rows (states, capitals)
i already declared the array to:

```
Dim states(49,1) as string 
states(0,0)= textbox1.text
states(0,1) = textbox2.text
```

im not sure what else to do because i have
am i storing this right? im not sure what more to do to store the rest of input into the array.

any help would be appreciated. thank you!

Comment: Easily researched [Arrays in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx)

Comment: Do you really need to use an `Array`? Is better to use  `List(Of`

Comment: @3vts youre probably right, but i have to do it this way

Comment: What is your trigger for putting the text box values into the array?  Like is the user supposed to type in the values and then click a button?  It seems like it'd be easy enough to have a button that when the user clicks it, just find the next array index that is empty and put the values there that way (clearing out the text boxes as well).

Comment: @Andarta right im using a button to perform this. I just dont understand how to "find the next array index" do you know if im doing it right so far?

Answer (score 0):

Declare module/class scope variables:

```
Dim states(49,1) as string
Dim nextInd as Integer = 0
```

Then in your button click handler:

```
If nextInd <= 49 Then   ' Make sure you are not trying to fill values past the dimensions of the array

     states(nextInd, 0) = textbox1.text
     states(nextInd, 1) = textbox2.text

     nextInd += 1  ' To increment the next index to use by 1

     textbox1.text = ""
     textbox2.text = ""

End If
```

---

And then to display the contents of the array, you need a loop:

```
    ' Use a string builder so you can modify the same string object to show it all together in the message box

    Dim contents As New StringBuilder("")

    For st = 0 To 49
        contents.Append(states(st, 0) & ": " & states(st, 1) & Environment.NewLine)
        ' Or however you want To format it
    Next

    MessageBox.Show(Me, contents)  ' MsgBox is old - use MessageBox instead
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH.  I didnt realize you can store variables in an array.. that helps out a out! How do i display the array once it has been filled? Im using MsgBox(states(49,1)) but it just comes up as an empty window. Any reason why?

Comment: @Powda - Glad I could help!  Telling the message box to display states(49,1) is only going to display that one value.  Which, if that value has not been set yet, then it doesn't have anything to display.  I'll add a way to display the array contents in a message box to my answer.

Comment: @Powda - I recommend that once you have this code in your project and can build it, run it in debug mode so you can step through it....that will help to gain a better understanding of how the nextInd variable is being used to specify where in the array to put the text box values, and the st variable in the loop being used to then get the values in the array for building the string.

Comment: yeah, I've tried using the stringBuilder but its saying that the type 'StringBuilder' is not defined and is throwing me an error. Do i need to import something?

Comment: @Powda - yes, add Imports System.Text.  FYI usually when you hover over an error like that it gives you a link to 'show potential fixes' - in this case clicking that should provide importing System.Text as a potential fix (it's a very handy way to discover things like that).

Comment: @Powda - Did that work for you?  If the information I provided answered your question, would you mind marking it as the answer?